# jQuery add class only to this nested element on hover

Tags: jquery, this

I'm using this jQuery to add a class to a span when the mouse is over the li tag. It's for a navigation menu, this code is adding the blackfont class to all menu spans. How can I use `this()` to to have the blackfont class applied only to the li which the mouse is over?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#second-menu ul li").hover(
          function () {
            jQuery("ul#secondary-menu li a span.sub").addClass("blackfont");
          },
          function () {
            jQuery("ul#secondary-menu li a span.sub").removeClass("blackfont");
          }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: second-menu & secondary-menu ..is that a typo or both the same ?

Comment: so secondary-menu comes under second-menu ?

Comment: @ubercooluk yes, your answer worked I just can't select it now it's too soon, will mark it off in a few minutes. Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#second-menu ul li").hover(function () {
            jQuery(this).find('span.sub').addClass("blackfont");
          },
          function () {
            jQuery(this).find('span.sub').removeClass("blackfont");
          }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: or `jQuery('span.sub', jQuery(this))`. Isn't `find()` a little slower?

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#second-menu ul li").hover(
          function () {
            jQuery("span.sub", this).addClass("blackfont");
          },
          function () {
            jQuery("span.sub", this).removeClass("blackfont");
          }
    });
</script>
```

Just select the span inside `this` element, which is the one you are hovering.